# PHP: both if and else statements are fired when I use post

Tags: php

when I use $_POST, both the if and else statements are executed. But the weird thing is that only the foreach loop is executed and "Flag is 0" is printed to the screen. If I replace $Flag = 1 with $Flag = 0, in the else statement, the loop does not get executed. When I replace "isset($_POST['Back'])" with "1", again the loop does not execute and all is well. So how come both my else and my if statement execute when I use $_POST? Thank you for any input

File #1

```
$Flag = 0;
    if (isset($_POST['Back']))
    { echo "Flag is 0";
        $Value = sqlsrv_fetch_array(sqlsrv_query($dbhandle,'SELECT MAX([Protocol Branch]) FROM Import_Trial_Information'),SQLSRV_FETCH_NUMERIC);
        $Value = $Value[0];
    }               
    else {$Flag = 1; echo "Flag is 1"; }

    if ($Flag)
    { 
        foreach ($Database_Tables AS $Delete)
        {
            $Query = 'DELETE FROM Import_' . $Delete;
            sqlsrv_query($dbhandle,$Query);
            if ($Delete == 'Paper_Information') {$Protocol = array('','');}
            else {$Protocol = array(',[Protocol Branch]',',1');}
            $Query = 'INSERT INTO Import_' . $Delete . '([Paper ID]' . $Protocol[0] . ') VALUES (' . (string)$ID . $Protocol[1] .')';
            sqlsrv_query($dbhandle,$Query);
        } 
        $Value = 1;
    }
```

File #2

```
<div id = "Back_Button">
<form action="Import_Article_Advanced.php" method = "POST"><button name = "Back" ID = "Back" Value = "Back">Return to Previous Page</button></form>
</div>
```

Comment: What is $_POST['Back']? Check it's value before you ever started evaluating the conditions.

Comment: Avoid using 0 or 1 in if conditions. Instead use true|false literals...and also use the === equality operator that checks for type as well as value.

Comment: "both the if and else statements are executed. But the weird thing is that only the foreach loop is executed and "Flag is 0" is printed to the screen."

I realize sometimes code can seem like black-magic, but there's no way the if and else are getting evaluated unless both statements are being printed

Comment: ex...if($Flag === 0) guarantees that $flag has a current runtime primitive type of integer...and that the value is exactly equal to the literal int value of zero.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
  if (isset($_POST['Back']) OR !empty($_POST['Back']) OR $_POST['Back']!="" )
 { echo "Flag is 0";
    $Value = sqlsrv_fetch_array(sqlsrv_query($dbhandle,'SELECT MAX([Protocol Branch]) FROM        Import_Trial_Information'),SQLSRV_FETCH_NUMERIC);
    $Value = $Value[0];
}               
else {$Flag = 1; echo "Flag is 1"; }
```

Comment: You only need to use `!empty()`, this will check if an element is set and if it does not equal `null`.

Comment: It did not work, for some reason it still runs. Oh, when I first coded this I only used if/else and did away with the flag variable. The only way it seems to stop this statement from executing is to comment out the code that deletes from the tables in the database or to set flag = 0 in both the if and else statements. The strange part is that "Flag is 0" is sent to the screen even though the delete query has been executed. I am lost :(

Comment: you are getting nothing in the $_POST so every time else is executing, i guess

Comment: No, because if $_POST had nothing the if(isset($_POST)) statement would not execute, but "Flag is 0" is still printed to the screen. This of course does not occur if I do not press the "Back" button created in the second line of code I posted.

Comment: can you plz tell me output of this code only as it is
print_r($_POST);
$Flag = 0;
    if (isset($_POST['Back']))
    { echo "Flag is 0";
        $Value = sqlsrv_fetch_array(sqlsrv_query($dbhandle,'SELECT MAX([Protocol Branch]) FROM Import_Trial_Information'),SQLSRV_FETCH_NUMERIC);
        $Value = $Value[0];
    }               
    else {$Flag = 1; echo "Flag is 1"; }

    if ($Flag)
    { 
        
  echo "in else";
        $Value = 1;
    }